# Getting following error "ProviderARNs cannot be empty" while creating AWS cognito authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Am trying to create a cognito authorier while using AWS CDK,

```
const cognitoAuthorizer = new apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, 'rest-api-cognito-authorizer', {
      restApiId: api.restApiId,
      cognitoUserPools: ["xx-xx1_xxxxx"],
      type: 'COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
      name: "AWS",
      providerARNs: ['arn:aws:cognito-idp:xx-xxxx-1:xxxxxxxxxx:userpool/xx-xxx_xxxxxx'], // userPoolArn is userPool.arn value
      identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
    });
```

I have verified/reverified the user pool name  and ARN multiple times.
checked and rechecked the API and various example but still the same

at my wits end now ;)

Comment: Looks like you're using a aws-cdk v1, as most of those fields don't even exist in the docs. As it has [reached end-of-support last year](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/cdk-v1-end-of-support/), is there a possibility you could upgrade? CDK v2 seems to get the ARNs of the cognitoUserPools automatically.

Comment: actually I tried both v2 and v1 and nothing worked for me :

will try with V2 and post if I am able to make it work

Comment: Tried with V2 also but getting the same error.

any idea?

Comment: If you're able to get to at least run `cdk synth`, you can preview your CF template and go from there.